# Сортировка таблицы по id на возрастание/убывание

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, вопрос состоит в том, как сделать сортировку таблицы по ID на возрастание/убывание
Очень нужна ваша помощь

```html
<TR style="font-weight:700; background: linear-gradient(to top, #e0edf5, #c2dbe7);">
 <TD>Номер</TD> /*это название колонки с id*/
 <TD>Название</TD>
 <TD>БИН/ИНН</TD>
 <TD>Адрес</TD>
  <TD width="150">Редактирование</TD>
  <TD width="150">Удалить</TD>
        
</TR>
<TR VALIGN="CENTER" NOWRAP ALIGN="LEFT" BGCOLOR="White">
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=SEQ /]</TD> /*эта колонка я так понимаю и есть колонка с прописанными id*/
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=NAME /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=BIN /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=Address /]</TD>
 <TD align="center"> 

</TD>
</TR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нет сырых данных (нативные JS-объекты), по которым можно построить таблицу, то выхода два:

- Собственно, создать сначала нативные JS-объекты из таблицы, затем удалить все DOM-элементы `TR` и построить таблицу заново, используя функции `document.createElement\appendChild\insertChild`.
- Или можно удалить `TR` элементы из таблицы и положить их в массив. Затем отсортировать массив стандартной функцией сортировки в JS `qsort`, ну а затем встроить элементы назад в DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Кликайте на **номер**:

```js
document.querySelector('thead th:first-child').onclick = e => {
   const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
   const rows = [...document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')];
   rows.sort((tr1, tr2) => {
      if (parseInt(tr1.querySelector('td').innerText) < parseInt(tr2.querySelector('td').innerText)) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
   });
   tbody.innerHTML = '';
   rows.forEach(row => tbody.appendChild(row));
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<TR style="font-weight:700; background: linear-gradient(to top, #e0edf5, #c2dbe7);">
 <th>Номер</th>
 <th>Название</th>
 <th>БИН/ИНН</th>
 <th>Адрес</th>
  <th width="150">Редактирование</th>
  <th width="150">Удалить</th>
</TR>
</thead>
<tbody>
<TR VALIGN="CENTER" NOWRAP ALIGN="LEFT" BGCOLOR="White">
 <TD>4</TD> 
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=NAME /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=BIN /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=Address /]</TD>
 <TD align="center"> </TD>
</TR>
<TR VALIGN="CENTER" NOWRAP ALIGN="LEFT" BGCOLOR="White">
 <TD>&nbsp;1</TD> 
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=NAME /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=BIN /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=Address /]</TD>
 <TD align="center"> </TD>
</TR>
<TR VALIGN="CENTER" NOWRAP ALIGN="LEFT" BGCOLOR="White">
 <TD>&nbsp;3</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=NAME /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=BIN /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=Address /]</TD>
 <TD align="center"> </TD>
</TR>
<TR VALIGN="CENTER" NOWRAP ALIGN="LEFT" BGCOLOR="White">
 <TD>&nbsp;2</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=NAME /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=BIN /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=Address /]</TD>
 <TD align="center"> </TD>
</TR>
<TR VALIGN="CENTER" NOWRAP ALIGN="LEFT" BGCOLOR="White">
 <TD>5</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=NAME /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=BIN /]</TD>
 <TD>&nbsp;[LL_REPTAG=Address /]</TD>
 <TD align="center"> </TD>
</TR>
<tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо! но к сожалению не работает( мне нельзя менять исходный код